# Physics Simulation - Objects going through one another

Tags: animation, physics

I am doing a physics simulation and I am running into some trouble with meshes partially going through one another. I am simulating physics using constraints. I am simulating an anchor being reeled in. The problem is that the chains and anchor or intersecting at point in a way they should not be. **How can I have the chains colliding with each other?**

[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27057)

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try disabling *Disable Collisions* on all the constraint empties and using the *Mesh* collision shape for the links.

Comment: How can I easily do it for all selected meshes, If I uncheck the box with multiple selected it only deactivates it for the active selected.

Comment: @Vader RMB on the checkbox > *Copy to selected*.

Comment: I unchecked disable collision but the meshes are still acting up. what shape should I use for the chains?

Comment: @Vader *"Mesh collision shape for the links."*